# Copy row to other worksheets based on a column value in a table

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have a macro that can read the values of a table, and copy the rows to a respective names worksheet if it match.

Lets say I have a template and Sheet1 worksheets. (unable to embed image yet)
[Sheet1 Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36H45.png)

'template' worksheet is the source where if column F value match one of the ID in Sheet1, it will be copied to the respective group(worksheet)
Example - all rows that contain 123 in column F of template will be copied to 'North' worksheet.

I have modified parts of the code provided from the excel masters here. 
However it is throwing a error 'Object variable or With Block variable not set' at this code `UpdateWs ws(wsTosaveto), ur`

Any help would be appreciated..

```
Sub sliceNdice()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Const master_ws As String = "template"
    Const master_col As String = "F"    'AutoFilter column in Master sheet

    Dim OldBook As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim valuetoFind As String, wsTosaveto As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, lc As Long, ur As Range, fCol As Range, done As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook

    With wb.Worksheets(master_ws)
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, master_col).End(xlUp).Row   'find last row of template
        lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  'find last column template
        Set ur = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lr, lc))  'set the range of data
        Set fCol = .Range(.Cells(2, master_col), .Cells(lr, master_col))
        Set done = .Range(.Cells(1, master_col), .Cells(2, master_col))
    End With


    Set OldBook = ThisWorkbook
    'Find last row of Sheet1 table
    LastRow = OldBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Scan all rows of Sheet1 table
    For i = 3 To LastRow 'Start in third row. First 2 row for titles
      valuetoFind = OldBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
      wsTosaveto = OldBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value

      fCol.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=valuetoFind
        If fCol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
          UpdateWs ws(wsTosaveto), ur
          Set done = Union(done, fCol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
        End If
    Next i

    If wb.Worksheets(master_ws).AutoFilterMode Then
      fCol.AutoFilter
      UpdateNA done, ur
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Private Sub UpdateWs(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef fromRng As Range)
    fromRng.Copy
    With ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End With
    ws.Activate
    ws.Cells(1).Select
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateNA(ByRef done As Range, ByRef ur As Range)
    done.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    If ur.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        UpdateWs ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(NA_WS), ur.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End If
    done.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ur.Parent.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: what is `, ur` supposed to mean in the line that errors? seems like a typo that can be removed, to me

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 `ur` is the 2nd `Range` argument for `UpdateWs`

Comment: @BigBen yikes, i dont know how i missed that

Comment: `UpdateWs worksheets(wsTosaveto), ur` ?